# HTML5 input type="tel" takes out leading zero from the input number

Tags: javascript, html, validation, frontend

AN input type="tel" takes out the leading zero from the phone number, but if I put the zero like: 0-xxxxxx (zero and then dash or any other sign) then it accept it.
but if I put 0xxxxx then it takes out the zero.
I would be thankful if you can help me please.

```
        hasValidPhone: function() {
            var isValidPhone = /^\+?[0-9]*$/.test(this.val());
            return this.length > 0 ? isValidPhone : false;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine here.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_tel

Or Please provide the code.

Comment: <input name="cellPhone" placeholder="Mobilnummer" type="tel">

Comment: No but for me it is working fine. I wrote your line on the above link. It doesn't takes out the zero.